# Infopath > Where are repeating rows saved?

Tags: infopath

I have 2 questions:

Question 1:

1. I downloaded the [Absence Request Form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?av=zip140&ctags=CT001226194&queryid=cb65589b-8e99-4216-8c85-8379988e697a) from the microsoft template section
2. I opened the in design mode
3. Did a preview and date and time was pre-filled with today's date and time
4. I looked at the date and time properties and default value to blank
5. I looked at form load and rule and it was nothing that tell me how those controls got auto populated on form load.

Question 2:

1. There a "Absence Details" section as repeating table
2. Where could this be saved? or How would you save this data (like a master/child)
3. Also, the total hours sum is no where to be found but the total sum works

I did not see any code behind either. Little confused. Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the template yet, but one method for repeating tables is to use the double eval trick, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/04/05/569338.aspx. This allows you to concatenate everything and promote it, depending on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Did a preview and date and time was pre-filled with today's date and
> time   I looked at the date and time properties and default value to
> blank   I looked at form load and rule and it was nothing that tell me
> how those controls got auto populated on form load.

AFAIU, this template was created in Infopath Designer 2003 with custom code in JScript which editing (or even viewing) is not supported in later versions of Infopath Designer

If you remove JScript (by pressing **Remove code** button in Programming of **Form Options** < Info < File, on ribbon) , all the controls will stop to be auto-populated

[image]

BTW, this removal will enable custom coding in sopported by later Infopath Designers C# and VB.NET which was blocked by presence of unsupported for editing JScript

[image]

> Where could this be saved? or How would you save this data (like a
> master/child)

You save a form with data as XML file:

- in Preview/Filler, by going to File, on ribbon > Save As

straight in provided template.  Also additionally  determining Publish and/or Submit locations/options in Infopath Designer